# webpage not responsive even after adding the meta tag in head element HTML and also toggle functionality in developer tools not working

Tags: html, css

The webpage is not getting responsive even after adding the meta tag in head element in html code. Please suggest what could be the possible solutions for this error.

I was expecting that page will become responsive but it's not happening.

Comment: Please add your  HTML code here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to ensure that you are employing responsive design in your application (i.e implementing col and row design, using @media query to target different platforms / window sizes, and utilising % width etc.)

Unfortunately, as great as it would be, adding the meta tag in the head alone won't make your website responsive. Ensuring responsiveness in web applications is an art for sure, and takes time to become really good at!

Here is a good place to start:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zF6VSky4SIc
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yU7jJ3NbPdA
3. https://medium.com/swlh/everything-you-need-to-know-about-responsive-web-design-54c2059a7e99
4. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srvUrASNj0s (very thorough)

Hope this helps!